# axios delete object from nested array

Tags: javascript, axios

im using axios to fetch data form an api. and to make delete request.

here is what the array looks like:
[image: array]

i can get this array by using

```
const { data } = await axios.get('http://ipadress:5000/api/categories/61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ee')
```

and delete it using:

```
await axios.delete(`/api/categories/${61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ee}`)
```

my qeustion is how can i delete one object from the array. for example the 'Jewelry' object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a different API to delete the item from the nested array
something like this;

```
await axios.delete(`/api/categories/subcategory/${61......fo}/`)
```

Comment: is there a different way for example a filtering method before the delete. to delete object based on id. instead of creating a sperate route of sub category. thanks

Comment: @shanksu218 - I think you are asking about this 
`let id = obj.SubCats.find((SubCat)=>SubCat.name ==="Jewelry").id`
find will return an object on the other hand **filter** will return an array if you have multiple names with same key you can use filter then loop over the ids and delete those ids